# pybind11 module import or link .so dependencies macOS

Tags: python, c++, macos, dynamic-linking, pybind11

TLDR: How do I link a .so/import a dependency when importing my pybind11 module in python?

I am attempting to build a pybind11 module that, in parts, depends on the C++ part of a different python library. On Linux, I can just link that library in CMake using `target_link_libraries` -- which does not work for .so libraries on macOS (`can't link with bundle (MH_BUNDLE) only dylibs (MH_DYLIB) file`).

When importing the pybind11-generated module without linking in Python on macOS, I get an `ImportError: dlopen(/path/to/my_module.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace (__<mangled symbol that is part of the library my module depends on>)`. This can be prevented by importing the dependency itself in Python before importing my own module.

Is there a way to either link that library, or to ensure that Python imports the dependency before loading my binary when running `import my_module`?

I attempted putting the shared library file in a folder with an `__init__.py` that just first imports the dependency, and then `*` from the .so -- but that resulted in some imports not working any longer (e.g., `import my_module.my_submodule` fails).

EDIT: A working, although cumbersome, drop-in solution is to add a dummy module to the pipeline. I.e., rename the original `my_module` to `_my_module`, and create a dummy `my_module` that does nothing besides importing the dependency:

```
#include <Python.h>

PyMODINIT_FUNC
PyInit_my_module(void)
{
    PyImport_ImportModule("the_dependency");
    return PyImport_ImportModule("_my_module");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an ideal solution, but seemingly the best way to solve the import-before-binary problem, while also retaining the ability to use the imported module just in the same way as one would in normal cases. This is achieved by using a dummy module to import the python dependency (which contains the associated C++ dependency as .so), before importing the original module.

So here's how it is done, assuming CMake is used to compile the project.

1. Conditionally set the module name to _my_module instead of my_module if it is compiled for macOS:

```
if (APPLE)
    set(MAIN_LIB_NAME _my_module)
else()
    set(MAIN_LIB_NAME my_module)
endif()
    
pybind11_add_module(${MAIN_LIB_NAME}
                    src/source1.cpp
                    # your source files, as before
)
```

2. Add a dummy module that takes the original name, this one is then used to import the dependency and load the actual module

```
if (APPLE)
    pybind11_add_module(my_module macos_dummy.h macos_dummy.cpp)
elseif (UNIX)
    # in my case, on linux I just linked against the .so
    target_link_libraries(my_module PUBLIC my_dependency)
endif()
```

3. Define a `PYBIND11_MODULE` in your original module that takes the dummy name, so that it can be properly imported by Python later on (i.e., let Pybind declare the `PyInit_` function). Do this while keeping your original `PYBIND11_MODULE` (with the original name):

```
#ifdef __APPLE__ // If apple, a dummy module is added, so that the dependency can be imported before loading the actual binary
PYBIND11_MODULE(_my_module, m) {
    m.doc() = "dummy module; doesn't do anything; if you see this instead of the actual module, something went wrong.";
}
#endif

PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m) {  // the original module, left unchanged
// ...
```

4. Implement the actual dummy module, that is using Python's import mechanics to import the dependency, find the original module and pretend to have been that original module all along:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <macos_dummy.h>

typedef PyObject* (*PyInitFunc)(void);

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_my_module(void)
{
    PyImport_ImportModule("my_dependency");  // import the dependency, this is the entire reason this exists in the first place
    PyObject* obj = PyImport_ImportModule("_my_module");  // let python find the correct binary
    const char* actual_module_path = PyUnicode_AsUTF8(PyObject_GetAttrString(obj, "__file__")); // get the path of the binary found by python

    void* actual_module = dlopen(actual_module_path, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);  // access the binary
    if (!actual_module) {
        printf("Module %s not found\n", actual_module_path);
        return NULL;
    } else {
        PyInitFunc actual_pyinit = dlsym(actual_module, "PyInit_my_module");  // retrieve the actual module
        return actual_pyinit();
    }
}
```

and the associated header:

```
#ifndef MY_MODULE_MACOS_DUMMY_H
#define MY_MODULE_MACOS_DUMMY_H
#include <Python.h>

__attribute__((visibility("default"))) PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_my_module(void);

#endif //MY_MODULE_MACOS_DUMMY_H
```

That's it. From now on, given that both generated .so files are in the path, importing the module under the original name will now import the dependency too.